# XMLHttpRequest getting aborted on some Android apps

Tags: android, xml, http, webview

I am using XMLHttpRequest for fetching some XMLs through Android webview. While it is working on most apps, I have some apps where the request gets aborted with the error XHRUrlHandler status code 0. When I enabled charles proxy, I see that the app where it's getting aborted is making HTTP1.1 request, while the other app where it's working fine is making HTTP2 request. Also, charles log show 200 OK response in both the cases but I still getting request.onabort event in JS causing my application to break.